# custom transformation for radius in ggplot geom_polar

Tags: r, ggplot2, transformation, polar-coordinates

I'm plotting seasonal data using `ggplot2`. Since small values aren't visible well when I start the axis at 0 I want to offest the axis. I want the function values correspond to the area between the offset and the line, the transform for this would be `r = sqrt(y+offest^2)`. (Correct me if I'm wrong here.)

How can I use this transformation together with `geom_polar`? In the following Code the Transformation does not seem to be applied:

```
my_function <- function(x){1+sin(x)}

my_trafo_trans <- function() trans_new("my_trafo", function(y){sign(y)*sqrt(abs(y))+1^2}, function(r){r^2+1^2})

ggplot(data=data.frame(x=0), aes(x=0)) +
  coord_trans(y = "my_trafo") +
  coord_polar(theta="x") +
  ylim(-0.5, 2 ) +
  xlim(-pi, pi) +
  stat_function(fun=my_function,  geom="line", alpha=0.75, n=1000) +
  stat_function(fun=function(x) 0, geom="line") +
  theme_bw()
```

Compare the output of this with the output when you comment out the `coord_trans` and `coord_polar` lines respectively.

Is it even possible to use `coord_trans` and `coord_polar` together?

Comment: You can only use one coordinate system. Note that if you switch the order, you always just get the last one. But `scale_y_continuous` has a `trans` argument you can use. A simpler offset can be done by just supplying the limits though.

Comment: So try: `+ scale_y_continuous(trans = trans_new("my_trafo", function(y){sign(y)*sqrt(abs(y))+1^2}, function(r){r^2+1^2}), limits = c(-0.5, 2))`

Comment: Thanks I completely overlooked the `trans` agrument of `scale_y_continuous`, still have to play around a little bit with the transformation but it works.

Comment: On second thoughts though: while the `trans` argument of `scale_y_continuous` archived the correct display of the data, it's semantically different to transform the data and to map to a different coordinate system, so a solution without `scale_y_continuous` would be great.

Comment: While you are correct, this is the best one can do without writing a new coordinate system.